# C# - class gets not serialized in settings

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, settings

I have a class like

```
public class ASetting
{
  public Type AType;
  public string AString;
}
```

in the settings of my project. I only want to save the property *AString*. The class not gets saved. My problem seems to be the serialisation of the property *AType*. After trying out different ways I am a little bit confused:

Also **not working** is capsuling the property like this:

```
public class ASetting
{
  private Type AType { get; private set; }
  public string AString;
}
```

If I set the property to private, the class gets saved and it is **working**.

```
public class ASetting
{
  private Type AType;
  public string AString;
}
```

But I need to have the property *AType* public. So I tried to use the [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx)

```
public class ASetting
{
  [IgnoreDataMember]
  public Type AType;
  public string AString;
}
```

but this is also **not working**.

I read about the [SettingsSerializeAsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.configuration.settingsserializeas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it seems like the Attributes of the serialisation of settings are not the same like the System.Runtime.Serialisation Attributes.

Would be greate if anybody has an idea to solve my problem - ignore the property *AType* during the save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the XmlIgnoreAttribute on your property.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public class ASetting
{
  [XmlIgnore]
  public Type AType;
  public string AString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [NonSerialized] ? 
Here is a [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axwwbcs6(v=vs.110).aspx)!